# Magento 2 sales shipment view showing 404 admin page

Tags: magento2

After migrating Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.1.9 sales shipment view showing 404 page, can anyone help me to solve this?

How Can I debug this issue?

All logs are showing empty.

Comment: Anyone pls help

Comment: did u find any solution i m having same issue